# `:tab drop` in not supported in terminal

Tags: terminal, tabbed-user-interface

I use fzf to find/open files, but it always creates a new tab or replaces the current buffer. I want instead to use `:tab drop <filename>` but I get

```
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version
```

When looking at the docs for `:drop` I see `{only available when compiled with a GUI}`.

Is there a way to enable `:tab drop` for the terminal version of Vim, or some other way to get the same functionality; i.e., Vim will switch to the existing tab if the file is already open, otherwise it will open the file in a new tab?

Comment: Welcome to [Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com)! I don't see anything about GUI only when I look at `:h :drop`.

Comment: @JakeGrossman that message only shows up when the version of Vim is not compiled with GUI support. See the docs here: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:drop

Comment: Can you install gVim? I'm not sure why the gui support is needed, but I am able to use `:tab drop` in a terminal Vim on Windows, with gVim installed.

Comment: @HerbWolfe thanks! Installing gvim and then running it in terminal mode does indeed fix it. This seems like an issue with vim though, since it works in terminal it shouldn't be conditioned on gui support.

Comment: You could write your own command or function that would search open tabs for the file (ie, behave like drop), and invoke that?

Comment: `:tab` depends on the `+windows` feature. From version 8.0.1118 on this feature is always enabled. Although `+windows` has been included even in the tiny feature set, one could theoretically have disabled the `+windows` feature explicitly at compile time. You can check whether this feature is enabled in your terminal version of Vim you can execute `:echo has('windows')`.

Answer (score 3):

vim built with gui support allows ":tab drop " even in terminal mode, for example the ubuntu vim-gtk3 package supports it.